# Mongoengine ReferenceField-like solution for embedded documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongoengine

I have a the following super simplified situation:

```py
class test_embedded_document(EmbeddedDocument):
    some_value = StringField(max_length=150)

    def foo(self, value):
        print(value, self.some_value)

class test1_document(Document):
    list_of_embedded_documents = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('test_embedded_document'))

class test2_document(Document):
    reference_to_embedded_documents = ???# I would need to reference test1_document.list_of_embedded_documents[5]
    
    def bar(self, value):
        self.reference_to_embedded_documents.foo(value)
```

Is there a good way to do this? Currently I'm using what feels like a kludgy EmbeddedDocument class as a crutch:

```py
class EmbeddedReferenceField(EmbeddedDocument):
    parent_document = ReferenceField(Document)
    reference_path = ListField(StringField())

    def set(self, parent, *path):
        self.parent_document = parent
        self.reference_path = list(path)

    def get(self):
        cur = self.parent_document

        for i in self.reference_path:
            cur = cur[i]

        return cur

    def save(self):
        self.parent_document.save()
```

I know one way to solve this would be to make **test_embedded_document** a Document and use a ReferenceField to reference it, but in my use case it makes more sense to keep it as embedded.

Comment: Based on your question text, it looks like you already have a workable solution and are looking for ways to improve your code.  It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the code review forum, that looks like a great resource. I personally see both of my workable solutions to be unsuitable for my current need. I provided them purely to further demonstrate what I am asking and to avoid them as answers.